# Find when the method is convergent and monotonous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

For the following differential equation

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
u'(x)=\lambda u(x), \lambda=const<0, x∈(0,X], \\ 
u(0)=u_0
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$
where $y_m'$ is the value of the right side of the differential equation in the point $x_m$.

When is the method

$$
\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{h}=\frac{3}{4} y_{i+1}'+\frac{1}{4}y_i'
$$

convergent and monotonous?

I have the following solution:

$$
y_i'=\lambda y_i$$ So we substitude in the difference method

$$
\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{h}=\frac{3}{4}\lambda y_{i+1}+\frac{1}{4}\lambda y_i
$$

Then we express the method in the following form
$$
y_{i+1}=\frac{4+h \lambda}{4-3h \lambda}y_i
$$

The difference method is convergent when

$$
|\frac{4+h \lambda}{4-3h \lambda}|<1
$$

which is true when

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
h \lambda < 0 \\
h>\frac{4}{\lambda}
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

The first one is always true since $\lambda < 0$, so the method is convergent when the step $h>\frac{4}{\lambda}$

The method is monotonous when

$$
\frac{4+h \lambda}{4-3h \lambda}>0
$$

Which is true when $h<\frac{4}{-\lambda}$

Is my solution correct?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a typo, you should have $$y_{i+1} = \frac{4 + h \lambda}{4 - 3 h \lambda} y_{i}$$ And one of your conditions should be $$-4 +3 h \lambda < 4 + h \lambda \implies h \lambda < 4 \implies h > \frac{4}{\lambda}$$ where the inequality reversal came about as you assumed $\lambda < 0$.

Comment: I have edited that, thanks for noticing.

Comment: Your second condition is still wrong.